# Foreach from map go

Tags: foreach, go

I have a little question for you all!

How foreach each element in json file?

json:

```
{
  "keywords": "keywords1",
  "social": [
    {"url": "test1", "title": "test1"},
    {"url": "test2", "title": "test2"}
  ]
}
```

and this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    configFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")
    json.Unmarshal(configFile, &person)

    // foreach["social"]
}
```

Comment: If you show the person object, I may be able to give a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a map, you can use key, value := range mymap. Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    configFile, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("config.json")
    json.Unmarshal(configFile, &person)

    for key, value := range person{}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Method #1: query `map[string]interface{}` ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/fhO874T-f1)):

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  person := make(map[string]interface{})
  json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
    "keywords": "keywords1",
    "social": [
      {"url": "test1", "title": "test1"},
      {"url": "test2", "title": "test2"}
    ]
  }`), &person)

  social, _ := person["social"]
  fmt.Println(social)
}
```

Prints:

```
[map[url:test1 title:test1] map[url:test2 title:test2]]
```

Method #2: nice intermediate object ([play](http://play.golang.org/p/IKvlezB4w1)):

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  var person struct {
    Keywords string `json:"keywords"`
    Social   []struct {
      Url   string `json:"url"`
      Title string `json:"title"`
    } `json:"social"`
  }

  json.Unmarshal([]byte(`{
    "keywords": "keywords1",
    "social": [
      {"url": "test1", "title": "test1"},
      {"url": "test2", "title": "test2"}
    ]
  }`), &person)

  for _, i := range person.Social {
    fmt.Println(i.Url, i.Title)
  }
}
```

Prints:

```
test1 test1
test2 test2
```